# Laravel - Storage::files($user->email) returns unwanted forward slash to folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-storage

- Laravel 5.4
- XAMPP on Win10

I would really need to understand once and for all which method returns forward slashes and which one returns backward slashes.

I have saved my images in a folder named after each connected users email as:

`$userImages = Storage::files($user->email);`

this result gives me:

```
array:7 [▼
  0 => "userEmail@mail.com/88bt97XslJMpre4dpJZO0ZRV9EV9GQbJw3FcQ4u8.png"
  1 => "userEmail@mail.com/dBfhlwB5HtNatUUCchZkA5PmqAxqruZi1zV3x3Ue.png"
  2 => "userEmail@mail.com/kbdJkR0oydplRA773uo6GzbYMfPJrtWILuBcuUQB.png"
  3 => "userEmail@mail.com/LHn80pVlrCPEj0YJcy4U6v8kTCuAOU43HGmuBNMs.png"
  4 => "userEmail@mail.com/MHkX31Dv5WmLtR8TsW4DgLTsQKjMwDbOrz3OlU4u.png"
  5 => "userEmail@mail.com/tebwcupwS4vU3BOsiLT5TUO298ImY5DprTHWnCef.png"
  6 => "userEmail@mail.com/YdMHREMBIQbinBw8IqBvfOLjigt5CS0XNAEUE4Le.png"
]
```

Which is cool since now all I have to do is parse it in front, yet since I needed to give these URLs a prefix, I used `storage_path()` as follows:

```
@if($userImages)
        @foreach($userImages as $image)
            <img src="{{storage_path().'\\'.$image}}">
        @endforeach
    @else
        doesn't exist
    @endif
```

And getting now a mismatch of slashes as follows:

`G:\xampp\htdocs\laraGo\storage\userEmail@mail.com/88bt97XslJMpre4dpJZO0ZRV9EV9GQbJw3FcQ4u8.png`

The first slash follows `storage_path()`'s slash convention yet what I'm getting from my controller: `$userImages` array has a different slash convention.

I'd be happy if you can let me know if using storage_path is an issue or if there's another **Laravel method** I should use..

I would also be happy to know if there's a way to know which methods bring me which kind of path?

Thanks, Bud.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `storage_path()` to generate the URL, as the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-storage-path) says

> returns the fully qualified path to the storage directory.

This means that you get back the local path to the storage, that is the folder on your computer which, in your example, appears to be a windows computer, which uses backslashes in all paths. If you ran this on a unix based computer you would receive a path made up of forward slashes. However in this case you appear to be attempting to create a URL to display the image, this works for you because the URL generated refers to the images on your local machine. However this would not work if you tried to access the from any machine other than your computer. To create a valid URL to an asset you need to use the [`asset`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset) helper, that generate a valid URL to your asset.

Answer (score 0):

hmm i use env APP_URL when access

```
 <img src="{{ env('APP_URL').'/storage/'.$image}}">
```

Comment: first thanks for the answer Aan, but shouldn't there be any issue of security raising env on the front end like that?

Comment: you can set .env file permission to 755 when delpoying to server

Answer (score 0):

You can use [asset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset), This will generate a URL for an asset using the current scheme of the request (HTTP or HTTPS)

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/' . $image) }}" />
```

Comment: that gives me: `http://larago.dev/storage/userEmail@mail.com/88bt97XslJMpre4dpJZO0ZRV9EV9GQbJw3FcQ4u8.png` and is not accessible since link is broken and not working.

Comment: If this isn't working then `larago.dev` isn't pointing to your webserver and your environment isn't setup correctly.